# How to write an entity when I am creating a table that uses it's id as a sequence in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am writting creating a table in follwing manner

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test_seq INCREMENT BY 50
MINVALUE 1
MAXVALUE 1000000000
START 1
CACHE 20
NO CYCLE;

CREATE TABLE table_name (
     id integer PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('test_seq'),
     name varchar(40) NOT NULL
);
```

Noramlly I can use  @SequenceGenerator annotation to use the sequence. But is there any way to get the work done without expicitly mentioning the sequnce generation to generate the id value.

I have tried writting the following way

```
@Table(name = "table_name")
public class TestEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  private String name;
}
```

I get error **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "table_name_seq" does not exist**

It works when I use

```
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "test_seq")
```

But is there any way without mentioning the generation value?

Comment: You should rather use an `identity` column. As far as I know, JPA should be able to work with that (using `GenerationType.IDENTITY`)

Comment: I'm not clear what's the key issue here. Do you want to create and refer the sequence automatically or you just want to fix the `PSQLException`? The later issue will just use a sequence named with `table-name`_`seq` format, if you want to use it, you need obey the rule.

Comment: I want handover the id generation task to the database , not in entity . Is there any way to do that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have tried that as well. shows error. It only works when I write like  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "test_seq") this way

Comment: `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` together with `id integer generated always as identity` works for me.